# Why is the container of lines not centered? - Pixi.js

Tags: pixi.js

I just got started with Pixi.js. I want to put multiple lines in the center of the canvas and rotate them. So I put the lines in a container and set the pivit point on the center of the container. Then I set the position of the container to the center of the canvas, but it is not centered. Why?

I want the output not to be [image: How I want the output not to be] but
[image: For the output I want the 2 red lines be centered]

```js
var app = new PIXI.Application({ 
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  antialias: true
});
app.renderer.backgroundColor = 0x061639;
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

function createLine(offset){
  let line = new PIXI.Graphics()
  line.lineStyle(25, 0xBB0000);
  line.x = offset;
  line.y = 0;
  line.moveTo(0, 0);
  line.lineTo(0, 100);
  return line;
}

let line1 = createLine(0);
let line2 = createLine(50);
let container = new PIXI.Container();
container.addChild(line1, line2);
container.pivot.x = container.width/2;
container.pivot.y = container.height/2;
container.x = app.screen.width/2;
container.y = app.screen.height/2;
//container.rotation = Math.PI/180*45; //rotate 45 degrees

app.stage.addChild(container);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.2/pixi.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e5j1ftwb/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width` and `height` properties of the [`PIXI.Container`](http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Container.html) return the entire width and height of the [`PIXI.Graphics`](http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Graphics.html) including the `lineWidth` which may increase the box which is covered by the object.

But the pivot point (`pivotX`, `pivotY`) defines the center of the object in relation to the geometrically coordinates of the object.

This means that the box (`width` and `height`) covered by the lines is (75, 100), because the centered lines have a thickness of 25 and a distance of 50.

```
|------ 75 ------|

+--x--+    +--x--+
|     |    |     |
|     |    |     |
|     |    |     |
```

But the geometry has a box of (50, 100), because the distance between the geometrically points is 50.

```
   |--- 50 ---|

+--x--+    +--x--+
|     |    |     |
|     |    |     |
|     |    |     |
```

This causes that the object is misaligned by the half of the line width.

I don't know if this is a wanted behavior or it is some kind of bug. Anyway it *natural* behavior.

You can work around by "outer" aligning the lines.

```
line.lineStyle(25, 0xBB0000, 1, 1);
```

```js
var app = new PIXI.Application({ 
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  antialias: true
});
app.renderer.backgroundColor = 0x061639;
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

function createLine(offset){
  let line = new PIXI.Graphics()
  line.lineStyle(25, 0xBB0000, 1, 1);
  line.x = offset;
  line.y = 0;
  line.moveTo(0, 0);
  line.lineTo(0, 100);
  return line;
}

let line1 = createLine(0);
let line2 = createLine(50);
let container = new PIXI.Container();
container.addChild(line1, line2);
container.pivot.x = container.width/2;
container.pivot.y = container.height/2;
container.x = app.screen.width/2;
container.y = app.screen.height/2;

app.stage.addChild(container);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.2/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you improve _which may increase the are which is converted by the object._ part in the first paragraph? I think you made a mistake because I don't understand the sentence.

Comment: _"Anyway it natural behavior."_, Don't you mean it's unnatural behavior? Otherwise please explain.

Comment: @MatMis No, it feels natural. In the background matrix transformations are applied to vertex coordinates. In this case `width/2 == 37,5`. A translation by this offset causes the result of your question to vertex coordinates with a x component of 0 respectively 50.